# How to execute a shell-command in Vim, and have the result printed below?

Tags: command-line, vim

I'd like to edit shell commands from vim, and execute them from vim. Currently I use `!!sh` (pipes current line to command sh), but this removes the line itself.

Is it possible to execute the command in a shell, and paste the result below that line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Clausi [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23517/how-to-execute-a-shell-command-in-vim-and-have-the-result-printed-below/23529#23529), `yyp!!sh` yanks (copies) the current line to the register, pastes that line below the original one, and replaces the bottom one with the output of the command.

To save keystrokes you can map this action by adding the next line in the `~/.vimrc` file:

> map <F5> yyp!!sh<CR><Esc>

This way everytime <kbd>F5</kbd> is pressed in command mode, the line will be executed and the result will be shown below the line.

Answer (score 2):

What about copying/pasting the line before executing (something like `yyp!!sh`)?

Answer (score 0):

Type shell command in the buffer, for instance `last | head`,
and in command line mode `:read !^R.`
Of course instead of typing literally `^R` hit `CTRL-R` key combination.
Look it up in `:help c_ctrl-r`. `.` stands for "the last inserted text".
If the command is one word for example `vnstat`,
place cursor on that word, and type `:read !<cword>`.